# Google Maps Tiles - how to divide 30k coordinates into tiles

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers, cluster-analysis

Is it possible and effectively divide 30k (and growing) or more coordinates into tiles on Google Maps?

My goal is to index all coordinates - assign to a tile and than define a tile size for each zoom level.

On the client side marker manager will do the clustering for each tile (which ideally would have less than 200 points)

New coordinates will automatically be assigned to a specific tile.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this, it seems that all you need is a tilecahce

Answer (score 3):

you'll want [a quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

> A quadtree is a tree data structure in which each internal node has up to four children. Quadtrees are most often used to partition a two dimensional space by recursively subdividing it into four quadrants or regions.

Comment: Any examples that utilize this data structure?